# Why my code wont work without Dispatcher.RunAsync in Geofencing

Tags: c#

why this code wont work without Dispatcher.RunAsync and what does it do? without Dispatcher its throwing error at copying value to textv.Text " thats its on different thread"

```
     async void Current_GeofenceStateChanged(GeofenceMonitor sender, object args)
    {
        var reports = sender.ReadReports();

        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            foreach (var report in reports)
            {
                GeofenceState st = report.NewState;
                Geofence gf2 = report.Geofence;
                if (st == GeofenceState.Entered)
                {
                    textv2.Text = "Hello"; //XAML TEXT
                }
                else if(st==GeofenceState.Exited)
                {
                    textv2.Text = "Bye";
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Event `Current_GeofenceStateChanged` is being fired outside of the GUI thread and only the GUI thread can change GUI elements. `Dispatcher.RunAsync` says the code inside should run on the GUI thread so it works.

if you put the result on a string variable it will work if you only put:

```
  Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => textv2.Text = StringVariable;);
```

**EDIT:** I only noticed that you have XAML code later you can just put the string on a property and bind the property to the text value of the text box letting you free from the Dispatcher.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding StringVariable}"/>
```

and on the code just have

```
public string StringVariable { get; set; }
```

than on the method just set the value to the property

```
StringVariable = "bla bla";
```